# Shell script to append to very long lines

Tags: shell, sed, newline

In the very long line sample below how can I append `"***"` to end of line?

Tried using "$" in sed but replacement occurs not at end of line but *near* the end just after column 350.  See `"***"` below.

```
tail -n+2 filename.dat | sed s/"$"/"***"/

xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com|111150151744782|99149327|NONM|20110325|20110605|TE201107E||ESOK1A||2002|2003A|2004A|2005|2007|2008|2009|2010|2011|2012|2014A|2016|2017A|2018|2019|2020|2021A|3001|3002|4001A|4002|4003|4004|4005A|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||8A12329A***833493A9C52EF5D66419ED5|016|zzzzzz|41606299952
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `sed 's/$/*/g'`

(I am using `bash` on `Ubuntu`)

Comment: To expand on that, the problem is that you put double quotes around the `$` and `*` _inside_ the regex. They should go _outside_, so the shell uses them.

Comment: @Tom more so that he used *double* quotes instead of *single* quotes.  You **don't** want the shell to interpret the `$` or the `*` so single quotes must be used

Comment: The 'g' flag means 'globally perform the substitution'. As the match-pattern is /$/ which =s end of Line, using 'g' is unnecessary.

Comment: @SiegeX: Oh yeah, good point. Haven't done anything fancy in bash lately.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do appending. Appending is basically just attaching something to an already existing string. "Substitution" is not necessary. Just printing what you want out at the end is good enough.

shell:

```
   $ var=$(tail -n+2 filename.dat )
   $ echo "${var}***"
```

awk:

```
$ tail -n+2 filename.dat | awk '{print $0"***"}'
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts $_.chomp+"***"' file
```